# (SAS) how to name the column with the value of other variable

Tags: sas

given dataset 'temp' looks like this..

| index | code1 | code2 | code3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | P1 | P2 | P3 |
| B | P1 | P3 | P4 |
| C | P2 | P4 | N1 |

then I want to make new dataset like this

| index | P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 | n1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

My code is here...

```
%macro freq;
%do i = 1 %to 3;
    %do j = 1 %to 5;
    if substr(code&i.,1,1) = "P" then
        if input(substr(code&i.,2,1),1.) = &j. then p&j. = 1;
    if substr(code&i.,1,1) = "N" then
        if input(substr(code&i.,2,1),1.) = &j. then n&j. = 1;
    %end;
%end;
%mend;
```

But it's not cool :(

How can I create a new column whose name is the value of variables(code1, code2,...)?

Is there any other simple way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
data have;
input (index code1 code2 code3)($);
datalines;
A P1 P2 P3
B P1 P3 P4
C P2 P4 N1
;

data temp;
   set have;
   array c code:;
   do over c;
      v = c;
      d = 1;
      output;
   end;
run;

proc transpose data = temp out = want(drop = _:);
   by index;
   id v;
   var d;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this without a macro by using `ARRAY` and the `VNAME` function in a `DATA` step.

```
data want;
  set have;
  /* Initialize flag variables. */
  length P1-P4 3 N1 3;
  /* Define arrays. */
  array code [*] code1-code3;
  array flags [*] P1-P4 N1;
  /* Loop over the arrays. */
  do i = 1 to dim(flags);
    flags[i] = 0;
    do j = 1 to dim(code);
      if vname(flags[i]) = code[j] then flags[i] = 1;
    end;
  end;
  keep index P1-P4 N1;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to convert values into variable names is via PROC TRANSPOSE.  So first convert your wide dataset into a tall dataset. You could use PROC TRANSPOSE to do that, but to make your target dataset PROC TRANSPOSE will need some numeric variable to transpose.  So why not use a data step to make the tall dataset and include a numeric variable that is set to 1.

The PROC TRANSPOSE step will give you a dataset with either a 1 or a missing value for the new variables.  You can use PROC STDIZE to change the missing values into zeros.

```
data have; 
  input index $ (code1-code3) (:$32.) ;
cards;
A P1 P2 P3
B P1 P3 P4
C P2 P4 N1
;

data tall;
  set have ;
  array code code1-code3;
  length _name_ $32 dummy 8;
  retain dummy 1;
  do column=1 to dim(code);
     _name_=code[column];
     if not missing(_name_) then output;
  end;
run;

proc transpose data=tall out=want(drop=_name_);
  by index ;
  id _name_;
  var dummy;
run;

proc stdize reponly missing=0 data=want ;
  var _numeric_;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

One more alternative:

```
proc transpose data=have out=long;
    by index;
    var code:;
run;

data long2;
    set long;
    value = 1;
run;

proc transpose data=long2 out=wide;
    by index;
    id col1;
    var value;
run;

/* Convert missing to zeroes */
data want;
    set wide;
    array vars _NUMERIC_;

    do over vars;
        if(vars = .) then vars = 0;
    end;
    
    drop _NAME_;
run;
```

Output:

```
index   P1  P2  P3  P4  N1
A       1   1   1   0   0
B       1   0   1   1   0
C       0   1   0   1   1
```